# My first DART polymer project: No execution / testing possible, nothing works?

Tags: dart, polymer

I have created a polymer project. It generates a default app which reverses text entered into an input field. This works.

Then I tried to add a core-header-panel. I copied the code from the description page into the index.html file of the project:

```
<body unresolved fullbleed layout vertical>
  <core-header-panel flex>
    <core-toolbar>
      <div>Hello World!</div>
    </core-toolbar>
  </core-header-panel>

  <main-app>
  </main-app>

  <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</body>
```

This gets me 3 warnings on the displayed web page. Two say:

> Custom element found in document body without an "unresolved"
>   attribute on it or one of its parents.

I have inserted an unresolved attribute after the body tag. I do not understand why the error does not go away.

The third messages is:

> custom element with name core-toolbar not found

I added a line

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
```

but the error message did not go away.

Finally I outcommented the complete core-header-panel and nevertheless the page in Dartium still shows "Hello world" and all the error messages.

I'm lost here. The DART editor / Dartium "development system" seems to be useless. I can not even test the simplest things. What am I doing wrong? How do you work with this system???

BTW: I get exactly the same behaviour when I try to run this as Javascript in Firefox browser ...

Comment: You can ignore the `unresolved` message at first. This is just about [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). You can care about it when you got the app and elements working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a solution by accident. The problem was that whatever I changed in the sources the DART editor always transfered the initial errornous file to the browser, or at least this is what it looks like.

The problem disappeared when I switched to another polymer project which I had used as an initial tutorial project, run that one and went back to the above project. Suddenly the browsers were able to display the changed files.

Looks for me like an ugly bug in the DART editor.

Comment: You definitely need the element imports. I assume the problem of not serving the updated file is somehow related with `pub serve` run by DartEditor behind the scene having problems observing the directory for changes. Stoping and starting `pub serve` probably solved the issue. There is a red stop button in the `pub serve` output window which kills `pub serve`. `pub serve` is then automatically started again when needed.

Comment: I agree that it makes sense to add the `core-header-panel` import (the other one was already in, see above). But missing it was not the reason for the strange behaviour. Now that everything works again it makes no difference whether both imports are in or just one of them ... although I prefer to have both of them included for better code maintainability.

Comment: There has to be an import for each used element. When one element itself imports the other element it might not be necessary to import it explicitly again but I don't think this is the case with the elements in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an import for `core-toolbar` and `core-header-panel`.

You also need to add a dependency to the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
dependencies:
  core_elements: any
```

Otherwise I can't see anything wrong.
If this doesn't work, please try to run `pub cache repair` in your project directory (from command line).
If this still doesn't work please add the complete content of your `pubspec.yaml`, `pubspec.lock` and `index.html` to your question.

Comment: The imports make sense but don't help and are not really needed, probably things get imported indirectly. The dependency in pubspec.yaml was set up correctly at project creation by the Dart Editor. I could not try cache repair because the problem had already disappeared (see my solution below). Might check the cache repair next time I encounter such a scenario.